# How to move my wife from her shop to my house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I married Muiri, and I said I had a home in Falkreath. She already had kids and a Hearthfire house when I said that though. I waited for a while, and I found her in her shop still. How do I get her to move?

Comment: It's really unclear what your situation is at the moment.

Comment: Have you waited any amount of time? If not, I'd try waiting 24 hours. If this doesn't work, try telling her that you'd like to move to your house in Falkreath again.

Answer (score 1):

Try once if that wont work wait 24 hours to try again, this method should work.